# Apache Camel maven dependency issue with BundleContextAware and BundleContext

Tags: spring, maven, apache-camel

I'm trying to configure Apache Camel in Spring in the Java config way as detailed in this [example](http://camel.apache.org/spring-java-config-example.html). However I'm stuck at the dependency step because `BundleContextAware` and (transitively) `BundleContext` cannot be resolved. It seems that the necessary transitive dependencies are not downloaded. Here is my pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <apache.camel.version>2.9.0</apache.camel.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
  <version>${apache.camel.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
  <version>${apache.camel.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-spring-javaconfig</artifactId>
  <version>${apache.camel.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Here's a code snippet from the example:

```
/**
 * Router from a file system to an ActiveMQ queue and then to a file system
 *
 * @version 
 */
@Configuration
public class MyRouteConfig extends SingleRouteCamelConfiguration 
    implements InitializingBean, BundleContextAware {

    private BundleContext bundleContext;
    ...
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah this example was refactored to also be deployable in OSGi. And therefore there is some OSGi classes in the sample code.

You should just remove that if you do not use OSGi, eg remove the code about `BundleContextAware` and `BundleContext`

Comment: I logged a ticket to improve the example to remove the OSGi pieces - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-6755

Answer (score 0):

The non-OSGI MyRouteConfig example is available [here](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/examples/camel-example-spring-javaconfig/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/example/spring/javaconfig/MyRouteConfig.java)